# How to do I create and use an environment to store secure API authorisation details and tokens in Pycharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, virtual-environment

I have been learning Python using Pycharm for a few months and I am coming along ok. I am using an online course at my own pace. Some of the lessons are slightly outdated meaning that I have to try and figure out how things should work now on my own and on the whole, I am managing this but this one is stumping me.

I was asked to create an environment to store my secure API authorisations and tokens etc. All the answers that I find online for doing this in Pycharm don't seem to match how Pycharm works now. I have tried following a few online answers but nothing really gets this done. I feel it should be simple but can't work out how to do it.  I worked out how to do this in Replit but I really need to know how to create the environment in PyCharm and how to put things in it for use.

I am using PyCharm 3023.1.4 (Community Edition) and Python 3.11.

I have tried to follow solutions online and tried to see if I could just work this out but I haven't been able to solve this.